# Change integer + string to uppercase for string in column values in pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two questions about cleaning data in pandas.

If I have a column with values like below:

```
1 st ST,
10 th AV,
Main st
```

I would like to change them like below:

```
1ST ST,
10TH AV,
MAIN ST
```

uppercase for all strings and if we have integer, attach following string together (no space)

How should I do that in `pandas`?

Comment: Do numbers appear only at the beginning?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Yes, only at the beginning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove any white-space after a digit and capitalize all letters, you can use:

```
df['column'] = [re.sub('(\\d)\\s+', '\\1', (x.upper())) for x in df['column']]
```

**Explanation:**

1) `re.sub()` - Does text replacement with regular expressions.

2) `(\\d)\\s+` - Selects a digit in a capture group, followed by one or more white spaces.

3) `\\1` - Replaces the above selection with only the selected digit, thus removing the white-space.

4) `x.upper()` - Converts the strings to uppercase.

**[Test online!](https://repl.it/repls/WellmadeSilkyAccess)**

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html) and [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex pattern:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.upper().str.replace(r'(\d+)\s+(TH|ST|ND|RD)\b', r'\1\2')

print(df['col'])

0     1ST ST,
1    10TH AV,
2     MAIN ST
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! If I have other than TH/ST (e.g. ND, PL etc...), should I put (TH|ST|ND|PL) like this? Or is there any general way to do that?

Comment: If it's only a few, that should be fine. if there are a lot, maybe best to create a list of patterns and join with `'|'.join` method

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas apply function:

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['1 st ST', '10 th AV', 'Main st']})
df.col.apply(lambda x: re.sub('(\\d)\\s+', '\\1', x).upper())
```

Will result in:

```
0     1ST ST
1    10TH AV
2    MAIN ST
Name: col, dtype: object
```